# UISplitView selecting particular in left pane the related should display in righ pane

Tags: iphone

**I have one doubt** but I am not getting any idea on the particular query.
 In Split View Controller, 
**how to show the related information in right pane when selecting in left pane.**

Comment: when left pane changes data send a notification to right one using NSNotification. You can bind sender object in NSNotificaiton object and use it to get required data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have look at this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial. Hope this will help.